# Browser caching and history with HTML/JSON route

Tags: javascript, python, http, rest, flask

I have a route in my application with a single URL which responds differently based on the Accepts header in the request. The idea is that if the URL is entered in a browser, an HTML template will be rendered. If my client side Javascript requests that URL, JSON will be returned. Here is a simple example (Python / Flask):

```
# From http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/45/
def requested_json():
    ''' Determine whether JSON was requested. '''
    best = request.accept_mimetypes.best_match([MIME_JSON, MIME_HTML])
    return best == MIME_JSON and request.accept_mimetypes[best] > request.accept_mimetypes[MIME_HTML]

@app.route('/assembly/<assembly_serial_no>', methods=['GET'])
def assembly_get(assembly_serial_no):
    ''' HTML/JSON route for getting the details of an assembly unit. '''
    assembly_model_id = g.pcb_db.get_assembly_model_id_for(assembly_serial_no)
    if not assembly_model_id:
        abort(404)
    assembly_unit = g.pcb_db.get_assembly(assembly_serial_no)        
    if requested_json():
        return jsonify(assembly_unit)
    else:
        return render_template('assembly.html',
            assembly_unit=assembly_unit,
        )
```

This has been working nicely, until I ran into a hitch with caching / browser history. If the user has loaded a URL in their browser previously, but the most recent request to that URL was done by the Javascript with Accept: application/json, if the back button is used to return to that URL, the browser has the JSON version cached, and displays that instead of the HTML version.

I could differentiate the JSON and HTML URLs (eg, append ?json=True), but if there is a better way to do this by correctly using HTTP headers, I'd like to know what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to include the Vary : Accept header for this.

According to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44:

> The Vary field value indicates the set of request-header fields that
>   fully determines, while the response is fresh, whether a cache is
>   permitted to use the response to reply to a subsequent request without
>   revalidation