# server side for backbone.js application( serve index.html by rest api server)

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, backbone.js, webserver

Trying to figure out how to make a rest api server for backbone js application. The question is not how to keep track of requests and methods (post, get and others). 
Question is how to give to client the index.html page?

I found an example where the entry point to site is the root('/').  It gives the index page. The problem with this solution is that, if I'll go to url '/users' without going to '/' first - I'll get json list of users(without my entire site). I understand that it is the way how rest api works...

But I would like my site to give to clients the index page always when they connect first time. 
So I need on the server to keep track of whether it is the first connection and give index.html along with the data on request, if it is the first. Or one server sends the index, and the other server is rest api.

Looks like I'm a little confused, I hope for your help)

PS. I would like to see examples of code/frameworks and other interferences in Python (although this is not important, important to understand the idea)

Comment: This question / answer seems relavent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737307/browser-caching-and-history-with-html-json-route. Although the simple answer is to use different route end points for html and json (rest) responses. Do you need a json response from /?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused about how the web works.

When you open your browser and type `www.example.com` in to the address bar, your browser goes to `example.com` expecting to find an HTML page.  It doesn't matter whether it's the first or the hundredth time you visit that URL; your browser is going to do the same exact thing, and every time it's going to expect to get HTML back.

The same is true of a REST API, except with JSON instead of HTML (or XML, or whatever your site uses for your AJAX communication).  When you have some Javascript code that makes an AJAX request to `www.example.com/api`, it's going to expect to get JSON/XML/whatever every time.

Now, if your browser were to go to `www.example.com` and get JSON back, it wouldn't know what to do with it.  Similarly, if your Javascript were to go to `www.example.com/api` and get HTML back, it wouldn't know what to do with it.  The way the web works, everyone expects a given URL to do one thing, so if you built a site where how many times the user had requested a certain URL determined what that URL returned, both your browser and your code wouldn't work because they wouldn't know what to do with the response.

So, really the best way to handle things (and the way just about every site on the entire web does it) is to have different URLs for different parts of your site.  If your REST API is at `www.example.com/API`, no user of yours is ever going to type that URL in to their browser because they wouldn't even know it exists (and even if they did, they'd have no reason to do that).

If you really wanted to do something similar to your request you could have your server look at the request headers and then return back either an HTML page or an AJAX response based on them.  But again, I strongly recommend against that approach: it will be far far easier for you to simply use a separate URL for your API.